# Numpy Where () with All() on a 2D matrix

Tags: numpy, where-clause

```
A= np.random.randint(5, size=(25, 4, 4))
U= np.unique(A, axis =0 )
results = np.where((A==U[0]).all(axis=-1))
```

Using this Where function matches individual rows, I would like to match the entire 4x4 array not just individual rows.

here are example results:
(array([ 1, 97, 97, 97, 97], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64))

if all four rows were matched the results would contain the same index 4 times as its for the index 97 above, a single row was matched with the index "1".

I assume if the entire array was matched then just one index would have been returned.
An example of desired output if multiple indexes are supplied for one array:
(array([97, 97, 97, 97], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)

Comment: pls. include actual and desired output examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.where((A.reshape(A.shape[0],-1) == U[0].reshape(-1)).all(axis=1))
```

Let's see an example

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(5, size=(25, 4, 4))
>>> A[:3,...]
array([[[0, 2, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 3, 0],
        [4, 1, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 3, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 2, 1],
        [3, 3, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 1, 1]],

       [[4, 0, 3, 3],
        [1, 0, 4, 4],
        [0, 0, 2, 3],
        [4, 1, 2, 2]]])
>>> U = np.unique(A, axis=0)
>>> U[0]
array([[0, 2, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 3, 0],
       [4, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Now you to want find `U[0]` in `A` if I understood correctly. It's easier to match row by row, so let's reshape the `4x4` arrays into rows

```
>>> A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1)[:3,...]
array([[0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1],
       [4, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2]])
>>> U[0].reshape(-1)
array([0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Now we can compare them with `np.where` but if we're not careful we'll get an elementwise comparison, so we need to use `np.all(axis=1)` to be sure to compare them row by row:

```
>>> np.where(np.all(A.reshape(25, -1) == U[0].reshape(-1), axis=1))
(array([0]),)
```

**EDIT** it just occurred to me you can use multiple axes with `np.all` and avoid reshaping altogether:

```
np.where((A == U[0]).all(axis=(1,2)))
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please

Comment: It is odd to me that the all() appears to work only across rows and not across matrices.

Comment: @TimT by default it works on matrices,, the `axis` parameter is the key

Comment: @TimT see the edit, you can even use multiple axes and avoid reshaping!

Comment: there we go!  The axis is the missing gap in my knowledge. I don't think I have seen multiple axes in a solution as such.  Well done. :)

Comment: Do you know by chance why  axis =-1 doesn't work in this solution?

Comment: @TimT with `axis=-1`  `np.all` gives you an aggregated comparison checking for truth for all elements on each row of your `4x4` subarrays (it's reducing over last axis). You need the aggregated the truth value over all elements of each subarray, so you need both axis `1` and `2` which identify both their rows and columns